# Context Service giving Interim Errors

Tags: web8, dxa-1.5

We have a running website built on SDL Web 8.1 & DXA 1.5
Suddenly, the website is going down due to unavailability of Context Service. When checked in Context Service Logs, the below Error Log is found. The Service goes down, and when restarted, the site starts work fine. The website is running fine from last 20 Months, but suddenly it is giving errors since last 10 hours.

Please help.

Error Log:

```
ERROR ActorSystemImpl - Uncaught error from thread [ODataAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-44576] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
        at java.lang.Character.codePointAt(Unknown Source) -[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Unknown Source) -[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Unknown Source) -[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Unknown Source) -[na:1.8.0_121]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On further investigation of the issue, we found that the repository folder went missing for context service. We have to uninstall the service and re-install it from the fresh folder provided by SDL, and it worked fine. As per the suggestions above, we have increased the max memory as well. The service is running fine since then, and Site Performance is also good.

Thanks Hem Kant & Karim Mazzoni for the help.

Regards,
Sharad Kumar Sangal

Answer (score 5):

Please check the following

Please check the folder structure of context service installed with installation media (all files and folder) and see if there is anything is missing.

Also check the system memory

Try to increase the stack size of context service and re-install if possible

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say from the logs, but it I've seen similar things when the services have been running low on memory. Have you had an increase in traffic? Rolled out a new site section or something?

Try increasing the max memory of the context service and see if you get the same error.